# Install iOS simulators from the command line

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I have a CI setup with multiple slaves. I'd like to install different versions of the iOS simulator, but this needs to be done from the Downloads tab in the Xcode Preferences. Ideally there would be a command line tool that we could run to download and install specific versions. Does this exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about having the system keep track of the package receipts, you can just install them on one of your systems and then rsync /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes over to the other systems.

Note that after the transfer, I'd suggest doing 'sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService' on the other slaves since the service expects the profiles to be moved into place and might not respond well to the rsync.